# Trying to get leads from yelp

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get leads from yelp using python and beautifulsoup but I'm not able to catch the fields for phone name address and wesbite (optional).
I'm getting the following error here is my code I try to search and found different solution but they didn't work for me.

Here is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sys
import csv
import requests, re, json
## Get the min and max page numbers
pagenum=0

maxpage =0
## loop go thourgh the pages
while pagenum <= maxpage:
    newsu =pagenum
    newsu = str(newsu)
    csvname = 'cardealers'+newsu+'.csv';
    csvfile = open(csvname , 'w',encoding="utf-8")
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csv_writer.writerow(['Business name', 'phone' , 'address'] )

    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
    r = requests.get('https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Used%20Car%20Dealers&find_loc=New%20York%2C%20NY&ns=1&sortby=review_count&start={}'.format(pagenum), headers = headers)
    p = re.compile(r'PRELOADED_STATE__ = (.*?);')
    data = json.loads(p)
    print(data)
    pagenum =pagenum+1
    for item in data['searchResult']['results']:
        name = item['businessName']
        phone=item['phone']
        address= ([item['address'],item['city'], item['state'], item['postalcode']])
        csv_writer.writerow([name, phone , address ])
        print(name)
    csvfile.close()
```

here is the error message.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "\Python\Python36\scraper\scrape.py", line 22, in 
>       data = json.loads(p)   File "\Python\Python36\lib\json__init__.py", line 348, in loads
>       'not {!r}'.format(s.**class**.**name**)) TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'SRE_Pattern'

Comment: specify problem what is not working? you are doing SRE_Pattern to load in JSON.

Comment: i try to get the class of elements which is holding the phone address and name but the all classes are the same and I'm new so i don't know how to do it in other way i see about json response so i try to create it on json but now i'm getting error which i mention earlier

Comment: what do you want?

Comment: i want to get the leads from yelp like business name address and phone number? I'm just trying to get what I'm doing wrong

Comment: you have to use BeautifulSoup to get data from which you are requested for URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to read in a string that is not json format.

Essentially, this is what you are doing:

```
data = json.loads('THIS IS JUST A STRING. NOT IN A JSON FORMAT')
```

so you want to do something like: `data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text))`

You actually need to pull that out from the html. The other MAJOR issue though is that is not even within the html you are pulling...so it will always return an empty list.

Also, you are not iterating through anything. You start at pagenum=0, with maxpage page=0 and run while pagenum<=maxpage which means it's going to run forever.

The json structure with the data is in the html, but looks like it's within the Comments. So you'll need to parse that instead.

Also, why do:

```
newsu =pagenum
newsu = str(newsu)
```

simply do `newsu = str(pagenum)`. Do you really want a seperate file for each iteration? I just put it into 1 file:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
import math

## Get the min and max page numbers
pagenum=0
results = pd.DataFrame()
with requests.Session() as s:
        headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.87 Safari/537.36'}
        url = 'https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Used%20Car%20Dealers&find_loc=New%20York%2C%20NY&ns=1&sortby=review_count&start={}'.format(pagenum)
        r = s.get(url, headers = headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

        scripts = soup.find_all('script')
        for script in scripts:
            if '<!--{' in script.text:
                jsonStr = script.text.split('<!--')[-1].split('-->')[0]
                jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)

        totalPages = jsonData['searchPageProps']['searchResultsProps']['paginationInfo']['totalResults']
        resultsPerPage = jsonData['searchPageProps']['searchResultsProps']['paginationInfo']['resultsPerPage']
        totalPages = math.ceil(totalPages/resultsPerPage)

        ## loop go through the pages
        for pagenum in range(0,totalPages+1):
            url = 'https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Used%20Car%20Dealers&find_loc=New%20York%2C%20NY&ns=1&sortby=review_count&start={}'.format(pagenum)
            r = s.get(url, headers = headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

            scripts = soup.find_all('script')
            for script in scripts:
                if '<!--{' in script.text:
                    jsonStr = script.text.split('<!--')[-1].split('-->')[0]
                    jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)


            for each in jsonData['searchPageProps']['searchResultsProps']['searchResults']:
                if 'searchResultBusiness' in each.keys():
                    busiName = each['searchResultBusiness']['name']
                    phone = each['searchResultBusiness']['phone']
                    address = each['searchResultBusiness']['formattedAddress']

                    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[busiName, phone, address]], columns=['Business name', 'phone' , 'address'])
                    results = results.append(temp_df, sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)
            print ('Aquired page: %s' %pagenum)



results.to_csv('cardealers.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: that's what i call a home run. Thanks save my day and explanation i really love that.